# How to get fa icons to display in menu (wordless)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and I'm trying to get fa-fa icons to display next to the menu items.

It used to work but now it's just showing a blank box. Any ideas. Tried

```
fa fa-envelope
```

for 'post an ad'

Nothing.

```
<li id="menu-item-1499" class="Fa fa-envelope menu-item 
 menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu- 
item-1499"><a title="Post an Ad" 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
2/awpcp-place-ad/">Post an Ad</a></li>
<li id="menu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try `fa` instead of `Fa`? Class names are case-sensitive.

Comment: It worked for one, fa fa-envelope, but tried fa fa-login and fa fa-sign-in, nothing.

Comment: you may need to update your font awesome files. Some fonts seems not to exist in your css file